# Angular routing not working, it redirects me to the base url

Tags: angular

I am trying to use `angular router` to navigate from my page.

I have a `button` on click of which I am navigating to some other page.

My current url is: `http://localhost:4200/user/12345567`. From here I click on button to navigate away

Here is my `button` code:

```
leaveArea(){
    this.router.navigate([ 'account', 'dashboard'], {relativeTo: this.route});
}
```

I want to navigate to `http://localhost:4200/account/dashboard` on click.

But instead I get navigated to `http://localhost:4200`. For an instant (maybe a milli-second or even less), I do see the url as `http://localhost:4200/account/dashboard` before it navigates to `http://localhost:4200`. Is there something wrong with the routing logic?

**Edit**

I am adding  the `routeTrace` results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

**Edit**

Here is my routing file:

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: "", component: HomeComponent },


    { path: "account/dashboard", component: AccountDashboardComponent},

    {
         path: "user/:id", component: UserComponent
    }
];

@NgModule({
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes, { enableTracing: true })],
    exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Comment: If you ant to navigate to /account/dashboard, thenn why do you use `relativeTo: this.route`? You precisely do NOT want that path to be relative to the current route.

Comment: @JBNizet I have tried `navigateByUrl` and also tried without `relativeTo`. None of them are working

Comment: Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem, including all the relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply try using `router.navigateByUrl` like this -

```
leaveArea(){
    this.router.navigateByUrl('/account/dashboard');
}
```

PS: By appending `/` in the start of the string will consider routing from root level.

Comment: Thanks, but it is also not working. I am getting the same error.

Comment: This should work, there must be some error on that page, can you check the developer console?

Comment: Yeah I checked, no error. It navigates me to /account/dashboard for maybe a millisecond then it goes to the root url

Comment: Have you implemented AuthGuard concept in routing? May be some code won't allow you to go to that page. Because this code should work as per question

Comment: Even I thought so, therefore I have removed all the `authguards`. Still this issue is coming.

Comment: May be you can try by stoping and again running your code after `npm cache  clean -f` and `ng serve`

Comment: Or run the router with routeTracing enabled and post the content of the development console in your question https://dzone.com/articles/note-to-self-debugging-angular-4-routing

Comment: @PardeepJain Thanks, cache clean didn't work. Will try routeTracing

Comment: @PardeepJain I have added the routeTracing results. Can you please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: @helloworld Seems Authguard logic is still working, can you crosscheck that

Comment: @PardeepJain I have removed all the `unnecessary`  routes and have edited my question and added the routing file. There are no guards here. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Please try and change your routes to

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: "", redirectTo: "home", pathMatch: "full" }
    { path: "home", component: HomeComponent },
    { path: "account/dashboard", component: AccountDashboardComponent},
    { path: "user/:id", component: UserComponent }
];
```

And change your navigation line to

```
this.router.navigate(['/account', 'dashboard']);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the **blank** route *first*.

It needs to be *last*.

> The order of the routes in the configuration matters and this is by design. The router uses a first-match wins strategy when matching routes, so more specific routes should be placed above less specific routes. (https://angular.io/guide/router)

So...

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [

    { path: "account/dashboard", component: AccountDashboardComponent},

    { path: "user/:id", component: UserComponent},

    { path: "", component: HomeComponent}
];
```